# Дублирование в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, table

Дублируются поля tr в таблице.Но я написал js скрипт,который убирает дублирование.Но когда нажимаю на редактировать,то дубликаты появляются снова.

Скрипт :

```
    <script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
  var textsToRemove = ['Уточнение', '1-е сутки', '2-3 сутки', 'Оцифр.3с'];

  function removeDups() {
    var counts = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var row = rows[i];
      var tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
      var text = tds[1] ? tds[1].innerText.trim() : '';

      console.log('Processing row', i, 'with text:', text);

      if (textsToRemove.includes(text)) {
        console.log('Text', text, 'is in textsToRemove.');

        counts[text] = (counts[text] || 0) + 1;
        console.log('Count of text', text, 'is', counts[text]);

        if (counts[text] > 1) {
          console.log('Removing row', i, 'with text:', text);
          if (row && row.parentNode) {
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // получаем все ссылки на странице
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  // добавляем обработчик событий на каждую ссылку
  links.forEach(function(link) {
    if (link.textContent === 'Редактировать') { // замените 'Редактировать' на текст вашей ссылки
      link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // вызываем функцию для удаления дубликатов
        removeDups();
      });
    }
  });

  // создаем экземпляр MutationObserver
  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      // вызываем функцию для удаления дубликатов
      removeDups();
    });    
  });

  // настраиваем наблюдатель
  var config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

  // передаем в наблюдатель элемент и его конфигурацию
  observer.observe(document.body, config);

  // удаляем дубликаты при загрузке страницы
  removeDups();
});
</script>
```

Есть таблица с такими полями : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как на фото должно быть 4,без дубликатов.Но я уже скрипт написал,который убирает дубликаты,а когда нажимаю на редактировать,то снова они появляются